# How to get audit entries from mapping table using Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am working on a spring boot project which uses Hibernate envers for auditing purpose. I am having couple of tables one having many to many relationship with another.

For example Foo is a table which has Many to Many relationship with Bar table as Set. Both foo and bar tables are getting audited in foo_aud, bar_aud tables and also the join table foo_bar_aud is also getting audited. I am using @JoinTable annotation for creation of join table and the entries are also successfully getting audited in the respective (foo_bar_aud) audit table.

But to get the values present in join table's audit table using Hibernate envers API in code. All the available methods are having entities as parameters and it is not fetching the auditing result of join table. Kindly help me out to get the entries.
PFB the image of foo_bar_aud audit table below.
The first column is revision number and next two columns are respective IDs of foo and bar and the last column is revision type (0-created, 2-deleted, 1-modified).

[image: iber]

Comment: Do you want the result in the same transaction or you want to fetch all the audits related to some join? You can also define an entity and run query using a composite key.

Comment: @Sonus21- Thanks for your response. I want to get the changed foo_bar_aud table's entry when I am getting the revision entries of the foo entity class using forRevisionsofEntity. Is that possible or else any other way is there for getting join table's audit table based on revision numbers?

Comment: My experiences with the Audit table has been very bad, it's very slow. Here you need to do some sort of joins across Audit tables to find what has changed. I would prefer just writing raw SQL to get this out.  You can also try to build an Audit query using `AuditQuery.add` method.

Comment: I hope the purpose of Envers API is to avoid the developer handle SQL statements and I am using QueryDSL for these purpose. But in Hibernate envers i cannot find any API method or way to get the entries from join table's audit table. In my case the join audit table (as show above), contains all audit entries with required data, but i cannot get the entries using available envers API. I might have missed something. Need help on the same

Comment: `AuditQuery innerJoinAuditQuery = AuditReaderFactory
.get( entityManager )
.createQuery()
.forEntitiesAtRevision( Customer.class, 1 )
.traverseRelation( "address", JoinType.INNER )`


https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers-querying-entity-relation-joins

It seems you can use traverseRelation